# Meaning of Off The Heels Of

Tags: idioms

The following sentence is a news report of the Hill.

> Greene is facing blowback from Democrats **off the heels of** a Washington Post report that she harassed Ocasio-Cortez on Wednesday and shouted at her as the two left the floor.

I know what 'on the heels of' means but can't find the meaning of 'off ...' in dictionaries. I think 'on ...' makes sense too in the sentence but it doesn't seem to be a typo.

Because 'on ...' means **following right after** may I guess that 'off ...' is **following a little behind**?

Comment: I think it's just a mistake for "on the heels of". A little googling shows that the expression is becoming more common, and it means the same as "on the heels of".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While "coming on the heels of" is more common, there is use for the "off" variant: https://ludwig.guru/s/coming+off+the+heels

The meaning is the same:  It refers to one event following immediately after another. In this example it also implies that one event is a direct consequence of the other.